# How to get out of while loop "...." and continue new line

Tags: python, read-eval-print-loop

How can I end writing while loop and continue a new line while writing the code in the terminal?

```
>>> while True:
...  print('W')
...
```

Comment: use `break` statement

Comment: @Mehmaam Probably not what OP means.

Comment: That's the Python [interpreter](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html) in interactive mode (aka REPL), not the "Python terminal". Also, typically you would use an [indent of 4 spaces](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#indentation) in Python, not 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't end writing the while loop without executing the while loop. In your example, hitting return once more will cause the while loop to execute and print an infinite stream of "W" + newline.

If you want to write more code in the terminal without executing the while loop immediately, you need to define a function. Then you can type out the entire function definition without executing any of the code. Hit return one more time to complete the function definition. The prompt will change from "..." back to ">>>". Then you can call your new function to execute the code.

```
>>> def infinite_loop():
...     while True:
...         print("W")
...     print("this line will never print")
...
>>> infinite_loop()
```

Comment: thanx thats what i meant

Answer (score 1):

Hit enter one more time. A blank line will end the loop.

```
>>> while True:
...  print('W')
... 
W
W
W
W
W
<snip>
```